# Filter JSON in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, filter

I have the following JSON in a Powershell variable:

```
{
  "Object1": {
    "name": "asdf1",
    "criteria": 2
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}
```

I want to get JSON where the value of *criteria* is 1. The result therefore should look as follows:

```
{
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}
```

I made an attempt with the following code:

```
$json | Get-ObjectMembers | Select-Object | where { $_.value.criteria -eq 1 };
```

While this basically goes into the right direction, it is *not* what I want exactly, because the result looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
}
```

See that the `Object2` information is lost and one depth-level is lost.

How can I achieve the desired result as shown above?

Comment: What is get-objectmembers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, you're looking to only retain properties of interest from your single input object or, to put it differently, to remove properties you're not interested in.

Here's a PSv4+ solution:

```
$json = @'
{
  "Object1": {
    "name": "asdf1",
    "criteria": 2
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}
'@

($json | ConvertFrom-Json).psobject.Properties.
  Where({ $_.Value.criteria -eq 1 }).
    ForEach({ [pscustomobject] @{ $_.Name = $_.Value } }) |
      ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields:

```
{
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) solution.  with_entries temporarily turns a list of properties into key and value pairs.  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries (section id's in html come in handy)  (Json creators don't believe in arrays?)

```
$json = '{
  "Object1": {
    "name": "asdf1",
    "criteria": 2
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}'

$json | jq 'with_entries(select(.value.criteria == 1))'

{
  "Object2": {
    "name": "asdf2",
    "criteria": 1
  }
}
```